# Parsing XML in a C# Application?

Tags: c#, xml, api

Right now, I am getting a Google search's XML. However, the XML doc is so big, I can't find anything anywhere. I am wondering how I can find the answer on Google. By that, I mean when you Google "Capital of Florida" the box at the top says Tallahassee. I want to access that information but I am unsure how.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
var response = request.GetResponse();

var rstream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(rstream);
var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```

The last `Console.Writeline` obviously just shoots out a huge monster of an XML doc

Comment: You're looking for LINQ to XML.

Comment: care to elaborate what linq is

Comment: Are you parsing a response form some sort of an XML API, or are you parsing HTML?

Answer (score 0):

See this it uses LINQ to extract a piece of info from XML documents https://coderwall.com/p/qghcqw

Answer (score 0):

if you are requesting HTML, a good way to parse the data is using HtmlAgilityPack

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/